# Do not run an arbiter on systems that also host the primary or the secondary members of the replica set

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb docs state

> Do not run an arbiter on systems that also host the primary or the secondary members of the replica set.

However I could not find any explanation for this. Is it for preventing the arbiter go down together with a secondary or primary when a failure occurs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technical it is possible to run a setup like this, but you lost redundancy.

Let's say you have a server with AB and C where B is an arbiter running on the same server as A. If this server goes down, you've lost your majority and B can't elect a new primary. So if the wrong server goes down you have no redundancy.

Fortunately arbiters don't save any data, so a small and cheap server instance is enough to run them.

Comment: Isnt it the case that when AB goes down C automatically becomes the new primary since it is the only one running ?

Comment: No, because with Mongo you always need a majority to elect a new primary. So if you have got a replica set with 3 instances, you need at least two running instances to elect a new primary. If you have got a replica set with 5 instances, you need at least 3 running instances and so on.

Comment: Actually, a [quorum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum_(distributed_computing)) of votes is needed to elect a new primary. This is necessary to ensure that a) the node bearing the most current data becomes the new primary (on a qualified majority should agree on to ensure maximum consistency), b) to maximize availability (cluster still can provide decisions base on a qualified majority) and – coming back to the original question - c) to have the maximum tolerance against partitioning. Running the arbiter on one of the other nodes inevitably leads to a reduction of one of those factors.